# how to rotate an image using jquery animate() function?

Tags: jquery

i know that there are many ways to rotate an image including using CSS3 and jquery.i've tried every single one of them.
none of those ways was the solution to my problem.actually as i mentioned in the title i'm looking for a way to rotate my images with a nice easing or effect.and i've tried something like this and i knew that it won't work and didn't.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#myImage").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({transform:"rotate(27deg)"},500,'easeInExpo')
        },function(){
        $(this).animate({transform:"rotate(-27deg)"},500,'easeOutExpo')
    })
});
```

Please help me guys.i couldn't find a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your post I read you tried css without success, this works:

```
#MyImage{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: limegreen;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#MyImage:hover{
    transform: rotate(27deg);
}

<div id="MyImage"> Hi there </div>
```

[And here we have a demo for FF(28) and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/73CkG/1/)